# How to fix wrong letter spacing with custom fonts in jsPDF using html method

Tags: javascript, fonts, jspdf

I'm using .html method to convert an html to pdf with something like this:

```
 doc.html(content, {
  callback: () => {
    resolve(doc);
  },
  html2canvas: {
    scale,
    logging: true,
    letterRendering: 1,
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
  },
  dompurify,
  margin: 0,
  fontFaces,
});
```

fontFaces is defined as an array or objects like this (using google fonts):

```
{
  family: 'Balsamiq-Sans', weight: 'normal', stretch: 'normal',
  src: [{ url: 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/balsamiqsans/v3/P5sEzZiAbNrN8SB3lQQX7Pnc8dkdIYdNHzs.ttf', format: 'truetype' }],
}
```

In the html elements that I want to render, adding a css fontFamily attribute is enough to set the font

```
<span style={{ fontFamily: 'Balsamiq-Sans', ... }}>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground </span>
```

It actually works, as it uses the right balsamiq sans font to render the given text, but the spacing looks wrong.

This is how the input would look like in HTML page for balsamiq sans [image: Look in html]

But the resulting PDF looks very different [image: PDF output]

It's like the space between words is reduced, and this happens with a lot of fonts from Google fonts (but some of them work fine like Dosis or Oswald).

I've tried using [Font squirrel tool](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to generate web fonts to remove kerning, change x-height matching, etc, and use the resulting ttf in the fontface object config for html method, without any luck. I've also tried different options for stretch in the FontFaces object, from 'ultra-condensed' to 'ultra-expanded' with no effect.

I wonder if there is a way to change the spacing in the font or something that could help. I appreciate any advice on this, I've been searching for a couple of days with no luck.

**Update:**

I've tried embedding the fonts into the PDF both using fontFaces API in jspdf v2.5.0 as indicated [here](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml) and using addFileToVFS as indicated [here](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#use-of-unicode-characters--utf-8).

```
const font = '<base64 font content string>';
doc.addFileToVFS('balsamiqsans-regular-webfont-normal.ttf', font);
doc.addFont('balsamiqsans-regular-webfont-normal.ttf', 'Balsamiq-Sans', 'normal');
doc.setFont('Balsamiq-Sans');
```

In both cases I see the embedded font in the PDF using linux bash tool pdffonts:
[image]

Comment: Are you embedding the font in the pdf? Or are you relying on your device's installed fonts?

Comment: I'm embedding it with fontFaces object in html method, according to http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this ? I'm having the exact same issue and nothing I tried worked either

Answer (score 6):

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69705732/4073821), add `letter-spacing: 0.01px;` to your HTML `div` with content:

```
<div id="content" style="font-family: Balsamiq-Sans, serif; letter-spacing: 0.01px;">
```