# html2canvas multiple pages rendering

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

I have this part of code:

```
 export(){
    let data = document.getElementById('export_pdf');
    html2canvas(data as any).then(canvas => {
        let  imgWidth = 210;
        //let  pageHeight = 295;
        let  imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        //let  heightLeft = imgHeight;
        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        let pdfData = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        let  position = 0;
        pdfData.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
        pdfData.save(`Export${this.selected}.pdf`);
    });
  }
```

And this is my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let asset of assets">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Asset ID {{asset.id}}</h1>  
  <table class="export-items">
    <tr>
      <td>Product:</td><td>{{asset.productOfferName||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SA name:</td><td>{{uom.agreementNames[asset.saAgreementId]||asset.saAgreementId||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Asset ID:</td><td>{{asset.id||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="asset.serviceLocationId">
      <td>Location ID:</td><td>{{asset.serviceLocationId}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Order num:</td><td>{{asset.orderNum||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Order item num:</td><td>{{asset.orderItemNum||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Status:</td><td>{{asset.status||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Start date:</td><td>{{asset.serviceStartDate | date:'longDate'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Termination date:</td><td>{{asset.terminationDate ? (asset.terminationDate | date:'longDate') : 'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Created by:</td><td>{{asset.createdBy||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Modified:</td><td>{{asset.modified ? (asset.modified | date:'longDate') : 'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Modified by:</td><td>{{asset.modifiedBy||'N/A'}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

But in export when data is too big i get only first page. Any suggestion how can i get all data with multiple pages based on data?

Comment: been down this rabbit hole myself - I resorted to chunking the array and rendering a table per chunk - part of my code in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705309). A underrated alternative is using @media print css and calling window.print() and letting the client pdf the page. Same view will render (linux font issues aside) if you later switch to backend rendering via something like puppeteer.