Why does jsPDF.html truncate the first whitespace character from each text node?
jsPDF v 2.5.1
const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

  pdf.html('<h1>How to Train Your Dragon</h1>', {
    callback: function (doc) {
      pdf.save(`${journal.name}.pdf`);
    },
    autoPaging: 'text',
    jsPDF: pdf,
    windowWidth: 600,
    width: 600
  });
  

The output in the PDF is "Howto TrainYourDragon". Note the missing spaces between some words.
https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3742

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705309/jspdf-html2canvas-losing-spaces-and-misaligning-text-generally
